# Android Studio firestore get name of user with highest points

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show what person has the most points currently in a scoreboard at the top. I did this by writing the following query:

```
Query query = collectionRef.orderBy("points",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1);
```

However, this only outputs a query to another query and not a string which is needed.

I have tried converting the query to String which just outputs its name and then using query. get but none of these work.

Comment: Please add your database schema. Have you also added a `get()` call to your query?

Comment: As Alex commented, you need to `get()` the data of the query to execute it. See the documentatoion for that here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: I have user query.get but I don't know how to extract the documents out from that.

Comment: @AlexMamo https://i.imgur.com/inzh9mP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the name of the user with the biggest score, please use the following lines of code:

```
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Log.d(TAG, document.getString("name"));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output in the logcat will be the name of the user with the biggest score.

Comment: One additional question, this outputs a random user when all users points equals zero, but it gets no exception. Where would I put this?

Comment: In that case, you should add another constraint, for instance, another whereEqualTo call. For example, you can query the database for users with highest score and users who created the account earlier than the other.